# How to allow localhost URLs as valid URLs - In Validate Min Js

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I found a Jquery plugin from [JQueryValidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

I'm validating URLs which is entered in the `Textbox` on submit. Its working perfectly when i enter the hosted URL's. `Https and http` Like `https://www.google.co.in` and `http://test.com/`

**Demo :** [Here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)

The problem is when i enter asp.net mvc local host urls its not allowing as a valid urls. Like `http://localhost:65350/Test.htm`

How do I allow local host urls also throgh `jquery.validate.min.js?`

Is there any custom methods can be added for `Hosted urls and localhost urls?` which will be validated at same time for a field.

Comment: may be this help you http://jsfiddle.net/4Nv2d/1/

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/introducing-testing-domain-localtest-me

Comment: yes, localtest.me, not localhost.me

Comment: You simply need to create a new rule/method using the `addMethod` method.  Use the function from the plugin's URL method as your base code and modify it to suit your needs.  **So are you asking how to create a rule with `addMethod()` or are you asking how to write the custom URL regex that includes `localhost`?**

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I asking `how to write the custom URL regex that includes localhost`.

Comment: @MohitArora Its accepting the local URL's whichi you are shared in the above fiddle Link. But Its accepting the URL's even there is no `.com` or `.net` or `.in`. Is it correct?

Comment: @RJK yes you are right but may be u can modify it you can allow `http://localhost` http://jsfiddle.net/4Nv2d/3/

Answer (score 1):

There's an additional method in jQuery Validation called `url2` that allows a url without a dot, thus allowing localhost url's.

Use the `rules` method to add it like so:

```
$( "#email_input" ).rules( "add", {
  url2: true
});
```

You can check out the source here:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/url2.js